# Remove yellow warnings in IDE

Tags: android, android-studio

How to delete the yellow triangle warnings in Android Studio? I had to reinstall Android, and I have forgotten how to remove the yellow warning triangles. I cannot have them on my projects. Thanks

Comment: It just warning msg...just Ignore it

Comment: do not ignore warning it will always lead you toward efficient and good code

Answer (score -1):

Yellow triangle are shown when you are not using something for example the imports but they are still there.
Yellow triangles in eclipse (And Yellow bars in Android Studio) means warning , you don't need to worry about it.
But a proper way is to remove the unwanted codes from your class and the yellow triangles will disappear.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: if you don't use an import you get an error, as in RED, not a warning.

Comment: I wasn't talking about not using the import , if you used an intent in your class it will it will introduce an import "import android.content.Intent;" automatically but if you remove the intent the Import still stays there which displays the yellow warning.